# Why is my AJAX .post not working in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

So this is my first Codeigniter project, and I'm about to commit seppuku.

Here is the situation:

I have a gallery of pictures.  When the user hovers over one of them a side div populates with more info called in by AJAX.

I just can't get it to work.  I keep getting this in Dev Tools>Network>XHR :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /ajax/getMoreInfo was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What am I doing wrong? and if anyone wants to drop some 'best practices', I'm all ears.  Specifically.. I have seen other examples where ajax parameters are passed via the URL sent with $.post (ajax/getMoreInfo/ID) and not as a variable as I do here.  Am I completely wrong?  (Even though I dont think that is the cause of my 404).

Here is my JS function called on hover

```
function showDataWindow(){

    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var thisIDpos = thisClass.indexOf("id-")+3;
    var thisID = thisClass.substr(thisIDpos, 3);
    /// alert(thisID) <- alerts correctly
    $.post('ajax/getMoreInfo', 
        { ID: thisID },
        function(data) {
            .. do stuff with data
```

I have a controller named ajax.php in /controllers

```
<?php

class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
      parent::__construct(); 
  }

  public function getMoreInfo()
 {
      $ID = $this->input->post('ID');
      $this->load->model('Artist_model','',TRUE);
      $more_info = $this->Artist_model->get_more_info($ID);
      echo json_encode($more_info);
  }
}
```

And my model in /models...

```
<?php 
class Artist_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function get_more_info($ID)
{        
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `NOIRusers` WHERE `UID` = `$ID`');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           foreach ($query->result() as $result)
           {

                $moreInfo['memberID'] =$result->UID;
                $moreInfo['firstName'] =$result->UFname;
                $moreInfo['lastName'] =$result->ULname;
                $moreInfo['large_image_location'] =$result->large_image_location;

                ..more of these..
           }
        }  
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried using full path instead of "/ajax/getMoreInfo" during ajax call? Or may be its because of improper configuration of .htaccess. You can try with "index.php/ajax/getMoreInfo" as well.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seppuku if anyone like me was wondering

Answer (score 2):

I think its an htaccess issue. Try using the following content in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: That seemed to help a bit.. it looks like I'm hitting my model now at least. (Pesky .htacess . one day I have to learn how to read that.)

 A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$ID' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM `NOIRusers` WHERE `UID` = `$ID`
Filename: /home/wwwberli/public_html/models/artist_model.php
Line Number: 46

Comment: Actually yes if you never had .htaccess set up it'll be that PLUS above routing issue.

Comment: You have a new issue with your SQL calls now, which is different from the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added it to the routes.php?

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

You will need to add it in here so CI knows what to do with 'ajax'.

Comment: Your comment confuses me...  if I am sending "class/method" like this, does it have to be added to routes.php?  I thought if I give CI a URL (eg 'target') .. it is going to look for a controller named 'Target'.  And 'target/action' will automatically look for a method 'action' in the Target controller class, no?

Comment: Nope... ajax is you're controller... so it need to add: $route['ajax'] = "Ajax"; so that CI knows what to do with /ajax/thing/

Comment: But after editing the .htaccess I seem to be hitting my model without changing anything in routes.php.  That seems to indicate that I am finding the Ajax controller and triggering the getMoreInfo method... how else would I be reaching my model to receive a database error?

Answer (score 0):

please try this following query if you can pass the id properly.

```
SELECT * FROM NOIRusers WHERE UID = '".$ID."'";
```

normally codeigniter use like

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('NOIRusers');
$this->db->where('UID',$ID);
```